# Is there a way to convert Android code to iOS code?

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine

I have submitted a game to the google play store.

The app was created using Unity and it is only compatible with the play store as it is an .apk file.

I want to try and submit the app to the iOS store as well but I am unsure on how to do this, what is the best way?

Comment: You need to build for iOS. You'll need a Mac and Xcode to do it.

Comment: You could also use the unity cloud build.

Comment: @Everts Good point. I always forget that since we do not use it. Does cloud build manage signing and uploading the iOS build as well?

Comment: I used it last time some 3 years ago but I believe it is meant to take care of all aspects of the production.